# Actions on Google: access Google Spreadsheet

Tags: actions-on-google

I have a Javascript program that queries a Google sheet with SELECT parameters and returns a row with two cells in JSON format. I want to build an Actions on Google webhook that calls that logic such that I can use the returned JSON values in my conversation.

I am not a programmer so I would appreciate help (and sample code) that might help me do this.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an out of box solution or a sample on our github for your question. However, there is an API for Google spreadsheet which it seems you're already using it

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest

One possible related example of using Google Assistant with the Google Spreadsheet could be vodo drive, which is built by one of the Google Assistant GDEs (Allen, https://twitter.com/afirstenberg) you can learn more through this document

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gElxZtMpHlTihbUbJoC5jlFf2QYMAv5ruuqreKc9rQw/edit

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I had tried the API; too many issues.

I tried Vodo, accessing a spreadsheet by voice in GA. Some comments:

1: Just the first level of folders in Google Drive is accessible, not folders further down the hierarchy.
2. Vodo could not respond to quite simple queries against the spreadsheet.
3. The product is a Black Box. Speak and the Assistant responds; no access to a Project to see the logic.

Regrettably Vodo won't hack it for me as I'm trying to see what variables get passed back and forth in Requests and Responses. Now I'm looking at Jovo...